# documentGetElementById does not fetch the correct value

Tags: javascript, null, return, getelementbyid

I'm a newbie to JS so I was just wondering.

I'm currently trying to get a list of different characters in a game going and what I have done with them etc.

For that particular reason I need to get the value of some checkboxes. I googled a lot and am now desperately looking for help.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='valor_1' value='0' onclick='javascript:toggle();'>
```

The function toggle() looks like this:

```
    function toggle()
{
    (this.value==1)?this.value=0:this.value=1;
    alert(this.value);  
}
```

For testing reasons I alerted the current value. If I now click the checkbox, it value changes and I get the correct return value in my alert windows.

BUT!

If I use this button right here:

```
<input type='button'' value='Valor_1 Value' onclick='javascript:alert(document.getElementById("valor_1").value);'>
```

I will always get the return value 0. Why is that? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get value 0 on click of button in alert because you are passing the value set of the checkbox i.e. 0. To get the value you want try something like this:

```
<input type='button'' value='Valor_1 Value' onclick='javascript:toggle(document.getElementById("valor_1"));'>

function toggle(cb)
{
    (cb.value==1)?cb.value=0:cb.value=1;
    alert(cb.value);  
}
```

Comment: Wow. That just made me see I was using "this" in a function. :l
Well... It now works when I pass the parameter, what Checkbox to toggle, but I only need to go like onclick="javascript:toggle(this)" to make it work.

Thank you very much ^_^b

Comment: If you pass this as parameter to toggle function in button's onClick it will be reference to button and not checkbox, so that is not possible. So please accept this as answer by clicking the accept as answer button.